# Creating Skill or custom action from bot composer in visual studio

Tags: bots, botframework

1. If I want to create this skill in pva then what is the manifest skill url
2. And how can I open this echo bot skill and the other bot in Emulator for testing ?

And one more question that I have is

If I have some topics in PVA and some dialogs in Bot composer for any ABC bot so how can I open this in emulator for testing?

I have gone through Microsoft documentation